# Is there a way to prevent MS docx document editing in OpenOffice?

Tags: ms-word, openoffice-writer

I know this is too strange question, but we have multiple authors of one document and some contributors use OpenOffice to edit document, originating and edited by majority in MS word. Document is quite complex with differently structured paragraphs and fonts, bullets, numbering, embedded pictures, references to comments under the line, copied/pasted sections pasted with source formatting instead of pure text etc., so generally "fragile" and maybe little bit exceeding expectations of OpenOffice authors for MS compatibility. Bottom line is about various formatting issues, glue-ing of some words (occasionally space is missing), page footer/header modified or completely disappeared etc. We are unable to control behaviour of contributors and editors to the extent I would like to have, so I am trying to findout whether is there a way how to force users to use exclusively MS word for particular docx and to prevent using anything else? *(I am not on MS payroll, I personally moved couple of people around me with "standard" document writing needs to OpenOffice, but incompatibility in this case creates useless redaction work for us.)*

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: I can't think of a simple way to do that. I first thought of an AutoOpen macro that checks the application name, but both OpenOffice and LibreOffice have macros turned off by default. The user has to install Java for macros to even work, so that's not a preventative. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, so you'll probbly get more answers at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

> whether is there a way how to force users to use exclusively MS word for particular docx and to prevent using anything else

To me, it sounds like a terrible idea to try to enforce this with a macro or similar (and it probably wouldn't work even if you tried). Instead, come up with a better workflow and communicate with anyone who may be involved so they know what to do.

First question, is the document under configuration control? For example, if a bad change is made, do you have a way of going back to a previous version? There are many different configuration management tools available, both free and commercial.

Next, I would strongly recommend making final changes with only one Office suite. Pick either LibreOffice (or Apache OpenOffice - is that what you mean by OpenOffice? The OpenOffice.org suite was forked several years ago) or MS Word to be the official editing tool, but not both.

If you pick MS Word, then people can still make preliminary changes to the document using LibreOffice. However, someone with MS Word will then need to use a Diff tool to see the changes and then use MS Word to incorporate those changes into the document. Or ideally, Track Changes would be turned on to make it easier to see what changes were made and who made them. Comments can also be added to explain why changes were made.

What is even better is to get people to send marked-up PDF files that contain their proposed changes. PDF files cannot be edited, which is good because it avoids the kinds of problems that led you to write this question, and also the formatting changes they made will not appear differently on another computer. However, this requires a certain amount of education so that everyone agrees to do it this way, and in my experience, that's not easy with a diverse group.

If you ever see that someone has made changes to the main document using LibreOffice, you or someone else needs to go back to the latest version not edited by LibreOffice and then use MS Word to incorporate all of the new changes.

At this point, if both suites have been used to edit the document, then I would probably start off with a new blank document and copy all of the text unformatted into it. This would require redoing all tables and other formatting. Otherwise, it's likely to be nearly impossible to get a clean document, and the underlying formatting may have no end to the number of problems that keep popping up.

Comment: Thanks to both John and Jim for your comments, I have to admit that you are completely right that this is more management (or psychological) issue than technical one. It is about Apache OpenOffice and we have no issues with "bad change" as such or version control. Problem is that document is somehow modified only by opening and saving in OpenOffice, not by intentional changes by the person with OpenOffice (deleted spaces between words, missing footers..), so sometimes subsequent MS editors notice and correct the same problem caused by OpenOffice editors multiple...

Comment: ...times. OpenOffice contributors fortunately do not have access to "master" copy, they send it by mail, but very likely we will change the process to import only their changes into master doc instead of replacing "master copy" of whole doc by the one exported from OpenOffice. So Openoffice user need to give us only partial doc with changes, (ideally also in PDF format in case of more complex look) and someone with MS need to import this into MS master doc in "controlled manner". ...

Comment: ...Very likely it will be more efficient and less problematic than to review always whole document and correct basic stuff with damaged styles and sections etc.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. Hope it goes well.